# Permission denied (publickey): SSH into EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, key-pair

I created a terraform configuration to launch an EC2 instance. My configuration is

```
    resource "aws_volume_attachment" "ebs_att" {
      device_name = "/dev/sdh"
      volume_id   = "${aws_ebs_volume.newVolume.id}"
      instance_id = "${aws_instance.web.id}"
    }

    resource "aws_instance" "web" {
      ami           = "ami-2757f631"
      instance_type = "t2.micro"
      availability_zone = "us-east-1a"
      vpc_security_group_ids=["${aws_security_group.instance.id}"]
      key_name="KeyPairVirginia"
      tags {
        Name = "HelloWorld"
      }
    }

    resource "aws_ebs_volume" "newVolume" {
      availability_zone = "us-east-1a"
      size              = 4
      encrypted=true
      type="standard"
      kms_key_id="arn:aws:kms:us-east-1:<account-id>:key/${data.aws_kms_key.ebskey.id}"
      tags {
        Name = "HelloWorld"
      }
    }
```

It provisioned an EC2 instance with a root volume and one additional EBS volume. I already have downloaded the specified key pair and did chmod 400 permission task. Now when I try to SSH into the instance it gives me **Permission Denied (Public Key) error.**

Why is this? Did I miss to specify any configuration in the terraform script?

Comment: Are you behind a firewall? Did toy try this from a corporate network?

Comment: The Security Group assigned to the EC2 instance allows SSH traffic on port 22. Can't be firewall issues. @Spiff

Comment: Are you connecting as the right user? Different AMIs use different default login users that get the public key added to as part of cloud-init. With Ubuntu AMIs this is `ubuntu` but others use `ec2-user` and I'm sure others use other users. What is your image based on?

Comment: arrgh!!! I knew that difference between different AMI's. I feel so much stupid. I specified wrong AMI here. Accidentally choose ubuntu AMI. Needed Linux with ec2-user login. Thanks @ydaetskcoR. Have a great day.

Comment: If you make the comment about user an answer, you can get a green checkmark!